Identify this cartoon with bipedal mice, including patriotic and comradeship messages
I remember seeing a cartoon around 1995 about a community of mice which were bipedal. The main character was a youthful slim mouse whose best friend was a fat one. They looked and behaved like humans between 15 and 18 years old.
In some episodes, the adventure involved going out of the mouse hole and running from cats.
In general, the message of each episode was either a moral, or about patriotism, heroism or comradeship.
I have a picture of it in my mind, but I can't remember the name of the animation.

@wbogacz, thank you for the corrections.

Was it Capitol Critters? 
(image from tvtropes.org):

The plot, from Wikipedia:

Begininng on a Nebraska farm, which was also home to a family of mice, including a young mouse named Max. While Max was on a trip outside to gather some corn, exterminators arrived to eliminate the mice. Once Max noticed the exterminators from a distance, he quickly returned to the basement only to witness the death of his entire family. Before Max's mother was killed after a failed rescue attempt, she told him to leave for Washington D.C., where his cousin Berkeley could be found. Upon his arrival in the nation's capital Max encountered a rat named Jammett who resided along with Berkeley in the White House basement. After meeting Berkeley, Max met a former lab rat named Muggle and Jammett's mother Trixie, who allowed him to share her son's room.


Is it Fievel's American Tails?

Fievel's American Tails is an American/Canadian animated television series, produced by Steven Spielberg's Amblimation animation studio, Nelvana, and Universal Cartoon Studios. It aired for one season in 1992, and continued Fievel's adventures from the film An American Tail: Fievel Goes West (1991).

Here's the opening credits:




@Caija, thank you, but it isn't. The one I am looking for is set in a more urban area.
